# How to create an auto-property faster in Delphi IDE?

Tags: delphi, properties, ide, automatic-properties

I need to create and manage many simple published properties. I call them auto-properties if they look like that:

```
private
  FTitle: string;
published
  property Title: string read FTitle write FTitle;
```

Usually I create them next way:

1. Adding property name and type:

   `property Title: string`
2. Selecting and copying property name `Title` to clipboard.
3. Appending the line with `read F` <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> `write F` <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> `;`
4. Pressing <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+C</kbd> and this will generate the private field

Is there any way to exclude steps 2 and 3 to add properties faster? Maybe it is possible to create some macro for this?

Comment: Er... You can usually skip steps 2 and 3 by skipping steps 2 and 3. It creates a procedure to set the field, but that procedure does nothing more than set the field. Is that undesirable for you for some reason?

Comment: wow! Never tried this. But without procedures it would be better. Don't want to flood the class definition.

Comment: Just write `property Something: Boolean;` and press `CTRL + SHIFT + C` and CodeCompletion will create a property field skeleton. And anyway those *procedures* are called setters.

Comment: @TLama Any secret IDE option to disable the creation of setters by Ctrl+Shift+C?

Comment: I suppose if you really want, you could create all properties with Ctrl-Shift-C, and then replace `write Set` with `write F` and remove the `Set` procedures in one go.

Comment: Using LiveTemplates (introduced in Delphi 2006 iirc) you can type propf and hit Ctrl+J.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since Delphi 2006 you can use LiveTemplates.

In Delphi XE for example:

- type [`propf`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Live_Templates_Changes_for_XE) and hit <kbd>Ctrl + J</kbd> keystroke
- write the property name and hit <kbd>TAB</kbd> key
- write the property type name, hit <kbd>TAB</kbd> or <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key and you are done

You can find more information on how to write your own Live Templates here:

- [`Delphi Live Templates - http://delphi.wikia.com`](http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Delphi_Live_Templates)
- [`Creating Live Templates - http://docwiki.embarcadero.com`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Creating_Live_Templates)

Answer (score 5):

I use macros for that purpose.

For example I have model with fields

```
private
  FTitle: string;
  FName: string
  FAge: Integer
```

then I copy-paste the fields into published section and create macro

1. Goto first field and hit <kbd>Home</kbd>
2. Hit <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + R</kbd> to start recording macro
3. Use <kbd>Crtl + -></kbd>,  <kbd>Crtl + <-</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> keys for navigation and convert first field to property like **property Title: string Read FTitle Write FTitle;**
4. After that hit <kbd>Home</kbd> and go to next row
5. Finish macro by hitting <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + R</kbd>
6. For all other fields, just press <kbd>Crtl + Shift + P</kbd>

At first it seems difficult, but the skills will pay off.

Comment: And if you use GExperts you can add this macro to the Macro Library for future use.

Answer (score 1):

In XE7 type prom and hit <kbd>enter</kbd>. It seems faster.